# repeating "your" in a list?

Tags: repetition

I'm a French native speaker and I would like to know if "your" should be repeated as in the following example:

> I translate your document, your ad, your website.

Could we simply say:

> I translate your document, ad and website.

What would be the impact of both sentences?
Are both forms grammatically correct?

Thanking you in advance for your help, Ophelie

Comment: Is this meant to be a comprehensive list or are these just some examples of all the items you would translate?

Answer (score 1):

Use your second example, "I translate your document, ad and website."  You left the conjunction out of the first example, but I understand that you are asking about the repeating use of *your*.  It is OK to repeat the possessive pronoun, but, on the other hand, there is no need to do so.

Comment: I didn't add the conjunction 'and' in the first example as I thought it would sound "inelegant", perhaps I am wrong? Thank you, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Originals:
>   I translate your document, your ad, your website.
>   I translate your document, ad and website.

I'll assume you're writing to a customer.  First, the verb tense needs to be modified.

> I will translate... I have translated... I translated

So we'll use "will" and we have:

> I **will** translate your document, your ad, **and** your website.
>   I **will** translate your document, ad and website.

The difference is only in the emphasis of pointing out that you doing all three things.  For example, in verbal negotiation:

> Customer: Your price is $150, but your competitor said he would translate my document for only $100.
>   You:  But you need more than just the document translated, and you know I do good work.  I'll tell you what.  **I'll translate your document, your ad, and your website** all for only $120.  I know my competitor can't beat that or my quality.

Another scenario, this time written:

> Customer (posted work):  I need the following translated: Document, Ad, and Website.
>   You (in writing, and wanting to be concise but specific):  I will bid to **translate your document, ad, and website** for $120.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wish to create a writer's craft repetitive tri-colon tone to strongly express something, I would suggest using the shortest form or you would be guilty of tautology.